# What does Apple monitors on Apples' computers?

Tags: network, services, system-information

The fallowing IP's pop-up some times on netstat (all 4 uses tcp4):

17.167.140.65

17.158.52.58

17.172.232.91

And the most information I could get is that theses IP's belongs to Apple. Anyone knows what information does Apple gather?

Comment: iCloud, iMessage, facetime? Just their services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to set the terminology straight.

Apple does not Monitor anything on your computer.

It only does if you asked for it and gave it a permission.

So you are still 100% in control and no one from Apple is spying on you.

Each Apple application on your computer would allow you to set it up to use Apple service on line.

A simple thing like the Clock, if it is set to synchronize with Apples clock will do that using your Internet to connect to Apple server.

I can not speak for all, but the majority of non Apple apps also ask you if you allow them to use the Internet.

So at the end it is you who is in control.

For example most apps offer a service to automatically check for updates.

Answer (score 1):

From the "Security and Privacy" preference pane in System Preferences (In Mac OS x Mavericks):

[image]

> You can help Apple improve its products and user support by having your Mac automatically send Apple information from time to time about how it's working and how you use it.  This information is collected anonymously in a form that does not personally identify you.  Click on the question mark for more information on the types of data sent.  To learn more about Apple's Privacy Policy see: http://www.apple.com/privacy

Comment: The problem is that the option is unchecked

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which OS services are attempting to connect to those IP addresses, then you could try Little Snitch:

http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html